# RestKit v0.20.x: simultaneously mapping (transient) object and (core data) managed object

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

Suppose I want to send a request to the server with the json

```
{ "begin_session" : { "info" : "this is some info" } }
```

and I expect in response the json:

```
{ "token" : "this is a token", "a_objects" : [
    { "name" : "name of first a_object", "b_objects" : [
        { "name" : "name of first b_object", "type" : "some type value", "id" : "123" },
        { "name" : "name of second b_object", "type" : "some other type value", "id" : "124" }
    ], "id" : "id of first a_object" },
    { "name" : "name of second a_object", "b_objects" : [
        { "name" : "name of first b_object", "type" : "some type value", "id" : "123" },
        { "name" : "name of third b_object", "type" : "some third type value" , "id" : "125" },
    ], "id" : "id of second a_object" }
] }
```

I want to store "token" transiently and persist the a_objects in core data. Is this how I should do the entire process? First, I set up the objects:

```
@interface LoginToken : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *token;
@end

@interface AObject : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *bObjects;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aObjectId;
@end

@implementation AObject
    @dynamic name; @dynamic bObjects; @dynamic aObjectId;
@end

@interface BObject : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) AObject *aObject;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bObjectId;
@end

@implementation BObject
    @dynamic name; @dynamic aObject; @dynamic type; @dynamic bObjectId;
@end
```

These are the request parameters:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{"begin_session":@{@"info":@"this is some info"}};
```

Then I set up the mappings:

```
RKObjectMapping *tokenMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LoginToken class]];
[tokenMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"token"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *tokenResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:tokenMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"token" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKEntityMapping *bObjectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"BObject" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
[bObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name":@"name",@"type":@"type", @"id":@"bObjectId"}];
bObjectMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"bObjectId"];

RKEntityMapping *aObjectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"AObject" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
[aObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name":@"name",@"id":@"aObjectId"}];
[aObjectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"b_objects" toKeyPath:@"bObjects" withMapping:bObjectMapping]];
aObjectMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"aObjectId"];
```

Suppose `objectManager` is a correctly configured RKObjectManager. I set up the response descriptors:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *tokenResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:tokenMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"token" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKResponseDescriptor *aObjectResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:aObjectMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"a_objects" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[tokenResponseDescriptor, aObjectResponseDescriptor]];
```

And finally I'll make the request:

```
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"path" parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    LoginToken *token = [mappingResult firstObject]; // use this token transiently
    // coredata objects are auto saved
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // handle error
}];
```

Is there anything I need to be aware of if this is, in fact, the correct way to do it? Also, how do I set the inverse relationship from BObject to AObject...?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your CoreData file has the relationship configured properly (which it looks correct based on your object header files) then the inverse relationship is handled by the mapper. Otherwise, it should work as is.

Note that the token object will be persisted in CoreData as well so you might have to delete them that's the desired behaviour.